# MYSQL Cumulative Totals with SUM and Subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the below table:

```
CREATE TABLE `_loans` (
  `loan_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` float(7,2) NOT NULL,
  `term` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `app_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `_loans` (`loan_id`, `price`, `term`, `app_date`) VALUES
(1, 299.00, 24, '2019-01-23'),
(2, 774.00, 24, '2019-01-24'),
(3, 817.80, 24, '2019-01-24'),
(4, 279.99, 24, '2019-01-28'),
(5, 463.99, 24, '2019-01-28'),
(6, 0.00, 24, '2019-01-28'),
(7, 357.00, 24, '2019-02-02'),
(8, 386.98, 24, '2019-02-04'),
(9, 846.00, 24, '2019-02-04'),
(10, 713.99, 24, '2019-02-06'),
(11, 0.00, 24, '2019-02-07'),
(12, 579.00, 24, '2019-02-11'),
(13, 179.00, 24, '2019-02-13'),
(14, 0.00, 24, '2019-02-19'),
(15, 259.00, 24, '2019-02-21'),
(16, 249.99, 24, '2019-02-26'),
(17, 319.00, 24, '2019-03-02'),
(18, 1108.99, 24, '2019-03-05'),
(19, 319.00, 24, '2019-03-05'),
(20, 199.97, 24, '2019-03-06');

ALTER TABLE `_loans`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`loan_id`),
  ADD KEY `app_date` (`app_date`);
```

And the below query,  which gives a monthly summary of the table data:

```
SELECT 
MONTHNAME(w.app_date) month,
YEAR(w.app_date) year,
COUNT(*) contracts,
SUM(w.total_price) totals,
@running_total := @running_total + SUM(w.total_price) running_totals
FROM (
    SELECT 
        app_date,
        SUM(price * term) total_price
    FROM _loans l
    GROUP BY l.loan_id
) w
JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r
GROUP BY YEAR(w.app_date), MONTH(w.app_date) 
ORDER BY YEAR(w.app_date), MONTH(w.app_date) ASC
```

I need a running total of the values from the 'totals' column. Everything works well except the cumulative total, which is not accumulating.

```
month     | year   |  contracts |    totals    |    running_totals  
------------------------------------------------------------------
January   | 2019   |      6     |   63234.72   |    63234.71923828125
February  | 2019   |     10     |   85703.04   |    85703.04016113281
March     | 2019   |      4     |   46727.04   |    46727.039794921875
```

Comment: Note that price is often DECIMAL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working because of the `GROUP`ing. You need to nest the `GROUP`ing as a subquery and compute the running total from that:

```
SELECT monthname as month, year, contracts, totals,
       @running_total := @running_total + totals AS running_totals
FROM (SELECT 
          MONTHNAME(w.app_date) monthname,
          MONTH(w.app_date) monthnum,
          YEAR(w.app_date) year,
          COUNT(*) contracts,
          SUM(w.total_price) totals
      FROM (SELECT 
                app_date,
                SUM(price * term) total_price
                FROM _loans l
                GROUP BY l.loan_id
      ) w
      GROUP BY year, monthnum, monthname
) t
JOIN (SELECT @running_total := 0) r
ORDER BY year, monthnum ASC
```

Output:

```
month       year    contracts   totals      running_totals
January     2019    6           63234.72    63234.71923828125
February    2019    10          85703.04    148937.75939941406
March       2019    4           46727.04    195664.79919433594
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cf99f33c40a0a540168dc88f9b7d28e6)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is overly complicated.  The subquery is not necessary for the aggregation.  However, it is necessary for the use of variables:

```
SELECT month, year, total_price,
       (@running_total := @running_total + total_price) as running_totals
FROM (SELECT MONTHNAME(l.app_date) as month,
             YEAR(l.app_date) as year,
             MONTH(l.app_date) as mon,
             COUNT(DISTINCT l.loan_id) as contracts,
             SUM(l.price * l.term) total_price
      FROM _loans l
      GROUP BY l.loan_id, YEAR(w.app_date), MONTH(w.app_date)
      ORDER BY l.loan_id, YEAR(w.app_date), MONTH(w.app_date)
     ) l CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @running_total := 0) params
ORDER BY year, mon ASC
```